# Loading Page Fragments on main page using Jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use Jquery to resolve my below issue.

I have got below HTML Links.

```
<ul class="tabHead tabs-nav"> 
    <li class="tabs-selected" id="tab-1">
    <a id="tab1" class="load-fragment" href="/index.aspx"><span>Overview</span></a>
    </li>
    <li id="tab-2">
    <a id="tab2" class="load-fragment" href="/guide.aspx"><span>Guide</span></a>
    </li>
    <li id="tab-3">
    <a id="tab3" href="/flightschedule.aspx"><span>Flight Schedule</span></a>
    </li>
    <li id="tab-4">
    <a id="tab4" href="/specialOffers.aspx"><span>Special Offers</span></a>
    </li>
    <li id="tab-5">
    <a id="tab5" class="load-fragment" href="/photo.aspx"><span>Photos</span></a>
    </li>   
</ul>
```

First of all above HTML is generated dynamically, I have written a jquery on class="load-fragment", please see below

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
        $(".load-fragment").each(function() 
        {           
            var fname = $(this).attr('href');
            var lastSlash = fname.lastIndexOf('/');
            var fileName = fname.substring(lastSlash+1, fname.lastIndexOf('.aspx')); //taking out filename for adding it in dynamic DIVs

            var dynDivID = "divContent"+fileName;
            $(this).attr("id",fileName)

            var newDiv = $("<div>").attr("id",dynDivID).load(fname + " #tabs-container",function ()
            {               
                $(this).hide();

            });      
            $("#column2").append(newDiv); //adding new div in div column2  
        });    

        $("#tab1").click(function()
        {
            // load home page on click
            $(this).attr("href", "#");
            $(".tabs-nav li").removeClass("tabs-selected"); //remove selected from other tabs
            $(this).parent().addClass("tabs-selected");
            $("#divContentindex").show();
            $("#tabs-container").hide();
            $("#divContentguide").hide();
            $("#divContentphoto").hide();
        });
        $("#tab2").click(function()
        {
            // load about page on click
            $(this).attr("href", "#");
            $(".tabs-nav li").removeClass("tabs-selected"); //remove selected from other tabs
            $(this).parent().addClass("tabs-selected");  
            $("#divContentguide").show();
            $("#tabs-container").hide();
            $("#divContentindex").hide();
            $("#divContentphoto").hide();
        });
        $("#tab5").click(function()
        {
            // load about page on click
            $(this).attr("href", "#");
            $(".tabs-nav li").removeClass("tabs-selected"); //remove selected from other tabs
            $(this).parent().addClass("tabs-selected"); 
            $("#divContentphoto").show();
            $("#tabs-container").hide();
            $("#divContentguide").hide();
            $("#divContentindex").hide();
        });

});
```

If you see above code, i have added the dynamic divs **(divContentindex,divContentguide,divContentphoto)** to DIV "**column2**", I want to avoide the below code written above for hide and show for dynamic DIVs, I want it should also work as dynamic, there should not be any harcoded DIV ID as these ID are created dynamic above.

Please suggest!

Thanks.

Best Regards,
MS

Comment: That is what i want to avoid, can you please suggest!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
var lastSlash = fname.lastIndexOf('/');
var fileName = fname.substring(lastSlash+1, fname.lastIndexOf('.aspx')); // ...
var dynDivID = "divContent"+fileName;
$(this).attr("id",fileName)
```

By

`var dynDivID = "divContent"+$(this).attr('id');`

Add `newDiv.addClass('dynDiv');`
before `$("#column2").append(newDiv);`

And replace all

`$("#tabX").click(function() {  ... });`

By

```
$(".load-fragment").click(function() {
    // load about page on click
    var thiz = $(this);
    thiz.attr("href", "#");
    $(".tabs-nav li").removeClass("tabs-selected"); // ...
    thiz.parent().addClass("tabs-selected");
    $('.dynDiv').hide();
    $("#divContent" + thiz.attr("id")).show();
}
```

Should do the job (not tested)

Edited according to comment

Comment: You build the same jQuery object 3 times. You should use `var $this = $(this);`

Comment: @Peter just for my knowledge what is disadvantage of making same JQuery Objects 3 times, can you please suggest in above code.

Comment: @Solution - It takes time. So it's an efficiency thing. What you would do is at the top of your `.click()` function you would write `var $this = $(this)`. Like that you cache the `$(this)` jQuery object so you can use it later and not have to rebuild it. Then in your `.click()` function you simply use `$this` instead of `$(this)`. Basically do that anytime you use `$(this)` more than once.

Comment: That's the idea. Generally by convention variables that are jQuery objects start with `$`, so in this case it would be `$thiz`. But, obviously, that has no impact on performance.

Answer (score 0):

Short form:

```
$(document).delegate('.tabs-nav li a.load-fragment', 'mouseenter', function (ev) {
    var _link = $(this),
        _div = _link.data('dynDiv');
    if (_div) return;
    var newDiv = $('<div>').hide()
        .addClass('dynamic')
        .load(_link.attr('href')+' #tabs-container', function () {
            var onLoad = _link.data('dynOnLoad');
            if (onLoad) onLoad(this);
            _link.data('dynLoaded', true);
        })
        .appendTo('#column2');
    _link.data('dynDiv', newDiv);
});
$(document).delegate('.tabs-nav li a.load-fragment', 'click', function (ev) {
    var _link = $(this),
        _div = _link.data('dynDiv'),
        onLoad = function () {
            $('#column2 .dynamic').hide();
            _div.show();
        };
    if (!_link.data('dynLoaded')) _link.data('dynOnLoad', onLoad);
    else  onLoad();
});
```

I went with the load on mouseenter because it's a trade off between front-loading on dom ready (which can hinder page load time) and loading on click (which can hinder the user experience).  Predictvely loading on the mouseenter gets you most of both worlds, and $(document).delegate lets you put the script in the head, so you can live without the flash of unbehaviored content.  It does require a little inter-event communication to avoid displaying the content before it's potentially ready, but what's a little .data() between friends?